# How can i know which button was clicked and get its value in my view

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

## Search.py

```
 {% block search %}
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" name="bankname" type="submit" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Name
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                {% for key , value  in data_dict.items %}
                <a class="dropdown-item" value=key name="name" href="{% url 'details' %}">{{ key}} </a>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    
    {%endblock%}
```

the number of items in data_dict is not always same , so some times it has 2 or 3 or even 10 different names which leads to 10 items in the drop down.
I need to show details of the name  clicked in the drop down in details .html

## Views.py

```
    def details(request ):
        request.GET('name')
        data_dict = request.session.get("data_dict")
        context = {"data_dict" : data_dict}
        return render(request , "details.html", context )
```

i want the value of the  tab clicked in the drop-down in my view so i can display the details accordingly from my data_dict

Answer (score 0):

you are on the right track. However, I believe there is some JavaScript code missing where you try to set the value of the Submit button?

You should know that when you submit a form, the only a Boolean value get submitted with the name of the button that has been clicked. So to this work correctly you will need to add multiple submit buttons with different names.

Following your example, something like this should work:

```html
<form method="POST">
  {% for key, value  in data_dict.items %}
    <button type="submit" name="{{ key }}">Save</button>
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

```py
def my_view(request, **kwargs):
    button_clicked = None
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        if request.POST.get(key, False):
            button_clicked = key, value
    print(button_clicked)
```

I hope that helps a bit, let me know if you have any further questions.

Best -Joe

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am  fairly new to programming can you please tell me how do i do that

Comment: I updated my code sample to better suite your issue. Let me know if that isn't enough.

Comment: what is the second parameter in the GET method (False) i didn't understand it. will the button_clicked variable give that particular key which was clicked? , because my understanding is that it won't this way anyways i have tried it and this doesn't seem to work. Thanks tough

Comment: it returns none

Comment: @suyashjoshi sorry, I believe that is because your form didn't use the method GET but POST. I changed my example to POST.
To answer your question: request.GET or request.POST are dictionaries of sort. Every dictionary implements the method `get`, https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp. The second option argument is the default, which I wanted to be explicitly False. None would have done too, but this is probably a little more verbose.

Comment: thanks for the reply again but yes i did notice the POST think and i did correct it instantly no luck. it's a <a> tab not a button i hope you did see that not that it makes any difference. please help i really need to finish this part